# Easy way to copy formula extending the source row by 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, copy-paste

Is there an easy way to copy a formula (see "What I want", in that case simply `=B4` `=B5` `=B6`) increasing the source row by 1 instead of the excel standard taking the row in which it is copied (see "What I get", in that case `=B4` `=B6` `=B8`)? The pattern of the distance where the formula is copied is always the same (in that example always jumping over one cell). There is no offset in the source cells/rows.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming data starts from `Cell B4` then in `Cell C4` enter the following formula

```
=IF(MOD((ROW()-4)*0.5,1)=0,OFFSET($B$4,(ROW()-4)*0.5,0),"")
```

Drag/Copy down above formula as required. See image from reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW()),"",OFFSET(B$4,(ROW()-4)/2,))
```

[OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

`IF(ISODD(ROW()),"",....)` just returns blank every odd numbered row. (In some cases ISODD should be changed to ISEVEN.)

`B$4` is the starting point, and is anchored (`$`) to remain the reference as the formula is copied down.

[ROW](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) returns the current row number and we deduct `4` from it when starting the formula in Row4 to copy a cell in that row (so when placed in Row4 `Row()-4` gives `0` offset).

As the formula is copied down ROW() increments by `1` each row and since we only want it to increment by `1` every *second* row, `/2`.

Hopefully it is fairly obvious what to change if to start in a different row or to interleave with more than a single blank row.

Move the anchor (`$B4` rather than `B$4`), use COLUMN instead or ROW and move the final `,` in OFFSET forward one position (ie next to the other) if to copy across rather than down.